# Blocks vs Delegates

Tags: objective-c, delegates, objective-c-blocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do code blocks completely replace delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584404/do-code-blocks-completely-replace-delegates)

I just encountered the following declaration from a forum:

> "Delegates is the past. Blocks are the future."

1) Are blocks the *preferred* way to do 'delegation' duties over delegates?

2) Is there any particular benefit of using a delegate vs a block?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something new, they are two entirely different things that aren't a substitute for the other...

Comment: @Chris: both approach can be used for callbacks. so there is room for substitution

Comment: «So, as a rule of thumb, a delegate protocol is correct when there's a need for ongoing communication, the actions causing the communication are diffuse or the actions are emanating from a third source. Blocks are primarily associated with asynchronous actions and single-shot classes in particular.» http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584404/do-code-blocks-completely-replace-delegates/9035610#9035610

Comment: @vikingosegundo - I guess I was thinking of delegates in terms of things like `UIWebViewDelegate` or other delegates passed to views.

Comment: @Chris: and those delegate objects provide callbacks. as blocks do.

Comment: When implementing a protocol with delegate it seems more logical for me. Also compiler can track and show you warnings if you miss something.

Comment: Interesting discussion.  Is there any distinct benefit to using blocks over delegates?  For example, lower risk of cyclic links as is possible with delegation; etc.  Or for that matter, vice-versa.

Answer (score 25):

I think there's a slight misunderstanding in what delegates do and what blocks do.

In Objective-C, there are three ways to handle callbacks:

1. Delegation -> where you make one object the *delegate* of another object and you have to specify which kinds of events generated by the "parent" object the delegate object will respond to.
2. Target-Action -> typical in UI interactions, where a UI subview (button, slider, etc) generates an event based on some user input (for example a touch/tap) that is handled by a predefined event handler (typically some Objective-C method that the developer specifies).
3. Notification -> where an object registers itself with an instance of `NSNotificationCenter` to "listen" for events of any type and responds to one or more of those events.

A block is not by itself a way to handle delegation, or any other callback.

They are self-contained pieces of code that have access to the local variables and parameters of the calling method. They can be used to define behavior in a bunch of different contexts. The main benefit of a block (as I see it) is that it can simplify code by eliminating extraneous overly-specific methods that would clutter your codebase. Blocks help to localize code to where it makes the most sense: right there within the callback mechanism.

Basically, using them enhances readability and makes code more maintainable.

Whether these benefits make blocks the 'preferred' method of handling callbacks is definitely a matter of personal opinion and experience. ;)