# Can blocks be used as replacement for delegates?

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I want to write a custom delegate method to receive an event in one of my view controllers from another view controller. Should I use blocks here instead of delegates. Which is the preferred one ?

```
@protocol MyClassDelegate
-(void)doSomethingInDelegate;
 @end

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property id<MyClassDelegate> delegate;
-(void)doSomething
@end



@implementation MyClass
 -(void)doSomething
{
[self.delegate doSomethingInDelegate];
}
@end

  @interface MyOtherClass<MyClassDelegate> : NSObject
  ...
 @end
@implementation MyOtherClass
 -(void)doSomethingInDelegate
    {
NSLog(@"Doing something in delegate");
}
 @end
```

Comment: Decide which you prefer. Blocks is a lightweight option.

Comment: I have used delegates until now..but want to know how delegates can replace it?

Comment: Presumably you mean how blocks can replace a delegate with a protocol?

Comment: Exactly.. thats what I want to know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421803/blocks-vs-delegates

Comment: So blocks cannot be used as a replacement for delegates right?

Comment: If you mean can I supply a block to an object that is using a delegation pattern, then no, a block cannot replace a delegate. If you mean can I design my code to use blocks as an alternative to a delegation pattern then yes you can.  Should you?  That is up to you. Certainly one thing that I think is better about delegation is that if there are multiple callbacks from an object then a single delegate assignment can take care of handling all of them while using blocks would require you to assign a block to each event or callback

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey, I have just added the code which i want to change using blocks. Could you help ?

Answer (score 6):

In most cases, if you have a very small number of delegate methods (ideally just 1), then blocks may be a good replacement. If you have several delegate methods, then blocks can become awkward.

`UITableView` has dozens of delegate methods between `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. Configuring that with blocks would be unwieldy and make code reuse very difficult. If a particular way of "being the delegate" may be highly reusable (like in `UITableViewController`), then delegates are a much more powerful pattern.

On the other hand, if your delegate would wind up having just a single "thisActionFinished:` method, then a delegate is likely overkill and it's better to just pass a block. There are many cases that this is true, and we used to have to need to create a lot of one-method delegate protocols, and it was a bit of a pain. Blocks made that common pattern a lot easier.

But it's not a universal replacement for delegation, and blocks have many other purposes that have nothing to do with callbacks. So it's important to learn both techniques.

---

Looking to your specific example, there are several mistakes. Let's do it in both delegate and block forms.

### Delegate

```
// Since the protocol needs to know about the class, you need to warn the
// compiler that this class exists.
@class MyClass;

// Declare the delegate protocol. Delegate method names should follow this
// pattern with "did", "should", or "will" in their names. Delegate methods
// should always pass the delegating object as the first parameter. A given
// delegate may be delegating for several instances.
@protocol MyClassDelegate
-(void)myClass:(MyClass *)class didSomething:(id)something;
@end


// Declare the class that has a delegate. Notice that `delegate` should be `weak`
// here. In your example, it's `strong`, and that will almost always lead to a
// retain loop. With rare exceptions, delegates are not retained.
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) id<MyClassDelegate> delegate;
-(void)doSomething;
@end

// Do the thing
@implementation MyClass
-(void)doSomething {
    [self.delegate myClass:self didSomething:@"SOMETHING"];
}
@end

// The delegate object almost always has a strong pointer to the thing it delegates
// for. That's why you want the `delegate` property to be weak.
// Note that your syntax was wrong. "MyOtherClass <MyClassDelegate>". That's
// the new generic syntax, not the protocol syntax. Protocols go at the end.
@interface MyOtherClass : NSObject <MyClassDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) MyClass *c;
@end

// And the obvious impl
@implementation MyOtherClass   
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.c = [MyClass new];
        self.c.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)myClass:(MyClass *)class didSomething:(id)something {
    NSLog(@"Doing something in delegate");
}
@end
```

### Block

Let's do the same thing if this were a block-based API.

```
// If your callback takes no arguments and returns nothing, then you can
// use dispatch_block_t here. But often you need parameters or return
// something, and for that you should usually make a typealias. Welcome to the
// spiral world of block syntax.
typedef void(^MyClassCallback)(id something);

// Instead of a delegate, we have a callback. We might have several. We might
// have a block that returns the row height. But if you're doing a lot of
// that, just use a delegate. Note that blocks should always be `copy`.
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) MyClassCallback callback;
-(void)doSomething;
@end

// And here's how you use the block. It's just like a function.
@implementation MyClass
-(void)doSomething {
    if (self.callback != nil) {
        self.callback(@"SOMETHING");
    }
}
@end

// And the delegate.
@interface MyOtherClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) MyClass *c;
@end

@implementation MyOtherClass

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.c = [MyClass new];

        // And here's the syntax for creating the block.
        self.c.callback = ^(id something) {
            NSLog(@"Doing something in delegate");
        };
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Notice we don't need an extra method in the delegate just to hold one line of code, and we don't need to define a protocol. That's the big reason for the move to blocks for lightweight delegation. It keeps related code close together. But when the code gets complicated, "together" gets crazy, and blocks are not longer a good solution. Back to delegates, which do that very well.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the reply. Could you just help me in getting that code to be implement using blocks?