# Passing information back from UITableViewDataSource to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a ViewController with a UITableView. As I wanted to split out the data handling I created an own class that answers UITableViewDataSource.

This class is supposed to first fetch data from CoreData and afterwards from a REST API.

How can the DataSource talk back to the ViewController to tell it to call reloadData on the TableView?
What's the best practice here?

I thought about:

- KVO the DataSource's data and when the array change call `reloadData`
- Handing over a block (with `[self.table reloadData]`) to the DataSource which gets executed every time the data changes in the DataSource
- Make the table property public on the ViewController so the DataSource could call `reloadData` (which I don't really like as an idea)
- Have a property on the DataSource which holds the ViewController with the Table to use it as a delegate (which sounds to me like a loop)

Are there any smart ways to do it? Or even common practice how to solve this?

**Update:**

I'm less interested in code how to do implement a certain design pattern. I'm more interested in the reasoning why to chose one pattern over the other.

Comment: If you want to keep the code related to Data separate why not create a category on your view controller say `MyTableVC+DataSource` or something ? Will that work ? Or you really want another class to be the datasource ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d that doesn't work for me since I want to plug different dataSources into the VC to get different data from a different endpoint/core data request

Comment: Ok you are looking to reuse your VC. Then you as others have suggested, create an interface(protocol) and call these methods in the usual table's datasource. Other classes can implement these methods in protocol to give data to VC

Comment: @GoodSp33d The only thing is I can't make up my mind which why is the better design, whether it's delegate and protocol, passing block, send notification or ... I know how to implement them all but I'm looking for a good design and a reasoning why one is better than the other

Comment: There s some interesting discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9035610/366346) Perhaps it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Without more details, it sounds like you need a callback here. There are several methods that will work. If you have a 1 to 1 relationship (meaning your dataSource only needs to talk to the VC), then this is a good case for either:

1.) A delegate. Create your own delegate protocol for your dataSource and then have the VC adhere to that protocol (be the delegate).

2.) Do the same thing just using a block for a callback.

KVO will work just fine as well, but the above two are more in line with your scenario.

You *could* add a tableView property to your custom data source but that then blurs the lines of why you created that class in the first place.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think that delegate is a better design than KVO?

Comment: Using a callback vs KVO for this situation couples your classes together more tightly and will be more readable. You control when the delegate is fired but with KVO your observer will be called anytime it's subscribee changes. Perhaps you don't want your tableView reloading ever time there is a change to it's datasource. Suppose you use KVO to subscribe to changes on an NSMUtableArray, every time you add an object to that array, your listener(s)will be notified. What you likely want is to notify your listener after the last object is added to your array, thus only refresh your tableView once.

Answer (score 1):

For situations like this, I prefer delegates.

```
@class CupcakePan;

@protocol CupcakePanDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)cupcakesAreReadyForPan:(CupcakePan *)pan;
@end

@interface CupcakePan : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak) id<CupcakePanDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation CupcakePan
- (void)bakingComplete {
  [self.delegate cupcakesAreReadyForPan:self];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [cupcakes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return [make a CupcakeCell];
}
@end

@interface CupcakeViewController <CupcakePanDelegate>
@end

@implementation CupcakeViewController
- (void)cupcakesAreReadyForPan:(CupcakePan *)pan {
  [_tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but my main question is why to chose delegate over the other methods? I'm more interested in design than how to implement the design in the end.

Comment: It helps to compartmentalize your code, but it also makes the process flow more explicit. When using `NSNotificationCenter`, you're breaking that chain a little bit. Not only does it make the code more difficult to jump through (there's no hotkey to follow notification flows), but the debugger won't list the originating stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use `NSNotificationCenter` for these types of interactions.

In your datasource write the following code:

```
#define ABCNotificationName @"ABCNotificationName"
#define ABCNotificationData @"ABCNotificationData"

// ...

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ABCNotificationName object:self userInfo:@{ ABCNotificationData: data }];
```

In your view controller do the following:

```
-(void)loadView {
    // setup your view
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(datasourceUpdated:) name:ABCNotificationName object:dataSource];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void)dataSourceUpdated:(NSNotification*)notification {
    id data = notification.userInfo[ABCNotificationData]; 
    // respond to the event
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Note, that if you don't have any piece of data to communicate back to the controller it becomes even easier.  In your datasource write the following code:

```
#define ABCNotificationName @"ABCNotificationName"

// ...

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ABCNotificationName object:self];
```

In your view controller do the following:

```
-(void)loadView {
    // setup your view
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(datasourceUpdated) name:ABCNotificationName object:dataSource];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void)dataSourceUpdated {
    // respond to the event
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but my main question is why to chose notifications over the other methods? I'm more interested in design than how to implement the design in the end

Comment: @hashier When you use notifications to represent relationships rather than a protocol, objects are very loosely coupled with one another. This means when things change, and they usually do, it is easy to modify this code.  Quite frankly, the relationship between something like a tableview datasource and view controller isn't usually interesting enough to warrant a protocol definition, and in Objective-C it's very tedious to maintain these relationships in this way.

Comment: @hashier For example, adding parameters and removing parameters with `NSNotificationCenter` requires no code change to existing code, vs. a delegate would require a redefinition of the protocol, all implementing methods, and all tests.

Comment: @hashier Finally, delegation doesn't scale very well. Many times, delegation lends itself towards a delegate of a delegate of a delegate approach.  Each step of the way requires a protocol import, and an implementation detail on an interface that is not concerned with the problem at hand. This is a waste of time, and generally a nightmare to maintain. With `NSNotificationCenter`, all you need is an event name to listen to.  Searching for this name in the code reveals all usages.